# Typescipt remove null from Nullish properties and undefined from other properties?

Tags: typescript

Say I have a type like this:

```
type MyType = {
  a: string | null | undefined;
  b: boolean | undefined;
  c: number;
}
```

I want to remove the `null` from property `a`, and removed `undefined` from `b`, so I get this:

```
type NewType = {
  a: string | undefined;
  b: boolean;
  c: number;
}
```

I tried coming up with a utility type to do this, but for some reason its not working:

```
type CleanType<T extends object> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends infer TP
    ? TP extends null
      ? NonNull<TP>
      : NonUndefined<TP>
    : never

type NonUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;
type NonNull<T> = T extends null ? never : T
```

However, this gives these results:

```
type MyType = CleanType<MyType>
MyType: {
  a: string;
  b: boolean;
  c: number;
}
```

It took away the `undefined` even from the `a` property unfortunately. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the premise for the use of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that by copying `T[P]` to its own [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter `TP` (via [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types)), your subsequent check of `TP extends null ? NonNull<TP> : NonUndefined<TP>` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), and so that check will happen separately for each union member of `TP`. That means `string | null | undefined` will be checked for `string extends null` (nope), `null extends null` (yep), and `undefined extends null` (nope), and thus you get `NonUndefined<string> | NonNull<null> | NonUndefined<undefined>`, which is `string | never | never`, which is `string`.  Oops.

You really don't want to split `T[P]` into union pieces before checking it.  Instead, you should check it all at once:

```
type CleanType<T extends object> = {
  [P in keyof T]: null extends T[P] ? NonNull<T[P]> : NonUndefined<T[P]>
};
```

We don't want to check `T[P] extends null` since that will not work (`string | null | undefined` certainly doesn't extend `null`) but the reverse does `null extends string | null | undefined`.

Let's test it out:

```
type MyCleanType = CleanType<MyType>
/* type MyCleanType = {
    a: string | undefined;
    b: boolean;
    c: number;
} */
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8CwAoKUCGAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmUAPlFQK4A2rDUzVAJhAGbUIPANzZcAIyISA9jNYQ8VTtz6CqwsTigBjIiwC2EiGS0BfbNlCQoAYQVLEkADzwoEAB7AIvYlBkSAFYQOsAAfFComNoA2gAKUNRQANYQIDL8UPAAuvpsHJ7evlnx2VAA-FAAcjJUVfmupRFENVQAqrwCQjyNcdlh2GZa1tCtHWrdrhGoboU+PH6qXRo8FUwQAG4mUETww0jVtfXsU5FZ7l7zfizsaxpbZDtZllgjsCD2ilROKHYO30hnHAfgMsAB6ABUUDecE+jgOUXEuHwRFIlFoKk66k0SMk0jk-y0yN0eSMJnMUAhYKAA)